# open multi PDF at the same time VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

As you can see that we can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.followhyperlink) to open the PDF.

> expression.FollowHyperlink (Address, SubAddress, NewWindow,
>   AddHistory, ExtraInfo, Method, HeaderInfo)

In here the *Address* is *string*. But use this method, one time can only open one PDF. In VBA Excel area, is there any way to open multi PDFs at the same time?

Comment: Why not open them one by one, by calling `Workbook.FollowHyperlink` multiple times, e.g. in a loop?

Comment: that would OK. But I wonder if that would be possible.

Comment: VBA is single-threaded, so I don't think there's any better way than using a loop.